# Why does the Resources Received change so frequently for same URL (page.open(url))

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am currently working on fetching/**scraping** all the images being received on requesting a URL.

The problem i am facing is the response changes after few tries or is very inconsistent even for the same URL using the phantomjs.

I have tried clearing cache multiple times and at different location in my code but the the request numbers dont appear to be the same.

o/p
1st call to URL
19 images and total off 49 responses from server

2nd call
14 images and 48 responses from server

3rd call
14 images and 38 responses from server

[Output for execution twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN0et.png)

**phantomjs-2.1.1-windows
running a java-script code using the phantomjs command**

I am very new to Javascript, i have manged to write the following till now

```
var page =  require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "https://..........";

page.settings.clearMemoryCaches = true;
page.clearMemoryCache();
page.clearCookies();
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};

var imageCounter = 0;
var responseCounter = 0;


page.open(url, function (status) {
console.log(status + '*/*/*/*/*/*/**/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/')
    if(status=='success'){
        console.log('The entire page is loaded.............################');
        console.log('\n' + imageCounter + '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n');
        console.log('\n' + responseCounter + '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n');
        imageCounter = 0;

        page.clearMemoryCache();
        page.clearCookies();
        page.close();
        phantom.exit();
    }
});



page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {      
    if(response.stage == "start"){
        responseCounter++;
        var respType = response.contentType;
        
        if(respType.indexOf("image")==0){
            imageCounter++;
            //console.log('Content-Type : ' + response.contentType)
            //console.log('Status : ' + response.status)
            //console.log('Image Size in byte : ' + response.bodySize)
            //console.log('Image Url : ' + response.url)
            //console.log('\n');
            console.log(imageCounter + '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n');
        }       
    }
};
```

I want to get consistent response for the images at least, I am really confused how does phantom cache this kind of resources on second attempt.

Comment: Is the page static?  Could it be that the page has different content every time you load it?  It would help to know what url is...

Comment: The page has static data, for e.g "https://promo.bankofamerica.com/studentcards/", the page content does not change if watched on the browser.